# Is there an equivalent in Tcl of 'string to X' functions found in C stdlib.h?

Tags: tcl

There are standard functions such as `atof` and `atoi` in C's `stdlib.h` for converting strings to floats / integers (and to do the reverse too). Is there an equivalent of this in Tcl or do I need to write my own process for carrying out these tasks?

Comment: In Tcl, strings *are* X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Everything is a string](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3018) in Tcl, but functions that expect a number (like `expr`) will use that 'string' as an integer:

```
% set str " 123 "
 123
% set num [expr $str*2]
246
```

If you want to format a number in a specific way (like producing a floating a point number of a specific precision) then you can use [`format`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm):

```
% set str " 1.234 "
 1.234
% set fnum [format "%.2f" $str]
1.23
```

Comment: Early versions of Tcl used `atof` and `atoi` (or rather `strtol` and `strtod`) in places where floats and ints were required for processing. These days, a more efficient system is used (the `Tcl_Obj` system) that does some clever caching, but the effect is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, everything is a string in Tcl, so you can just use a given string as an integer or whatever else you need it as. The only caveat being that it needs to be something that can be interpreted as what you want to use it as (ie, you can use "a" as an integer)

You can test to see if something can be interpreted as the type you want using the `string is` subcommand:

```
string is integer "5" ;# true
string is integer "a" ;# false
string is list "a b cc" ;# true
string is list "{a b}c" ;# false
```

Answer (score 1):

I should note as well that equivatents to `atof` and `atoi` can be viewed as conversion of internal Tcl data structures to external *binary* representations.  This is done by the `[binary format]` command.

Answer (score 0):

One can test `string is double $x` before using $x in expressions.

E.g., `[string is double 1.2.3]`  returns 0

Answer (score -2):

In my case, this code worked:

```
set a [string trimleft $a 0]
```