# conversion string type into integer type in tcl script. like that a number is type of string and I want to increment it so how to fix it in tcl

Tags: tcl

How to convert string type into integer type in tcl script.like i fetch data from another file and it is string type. I want to increment that number which is string type so how to do it.

Comment: [Check This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150291/is-there-an-equivalent-in-tcl-of-string-to-x-functions-found-in-c-stdlib-h). You probably will get more information over here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tcl basically conceals all types from you; the value is the value regardless of its type, and all types are serializable as strings. It's common to say “everything is a string” and while that's formally inaccurate, the language conspires to make it appear as if it was true. Thus, if it looks like an integer, it *is* an integer from the perspective of `incr` (which is definitely the recommended idiomatic method of incrementing).

However, you can use the `scan` command to enforce integer-ness a bit more. (It's very much like `sscanf()` in C, if you know that.)

```
scan $myValue %d myInteger
incr myInteger
```

If you're going to use `scan` properly, you probably ought to check the result of it, which is the number of fields successfully scanned.

```
if {[scan $myValue %d%c myInteger dummy] != 1} {
    error "\"$myValue\" isn't a proper integer"
}
incr myInteger
```

You can also use `string is integer`; the `-strict` option should be used with this, for historical reasons.

```
if {![string is integer -strict $myValue]} {
    error "\"$myValue\" isn't a proper integer"
}
incr myValue
```

A lot of people don't bother with any of this and just increment the (variable containing the) value directly. It'll error out with a default error message if it is impossible.

```
incr myValue
```

Tcl always tries to tell you what went wrong when a problem occurs, and also where that problem actually was. Do remember to check the `errorInfo` global variable for a stack trace…

Answer (score 3):

Ashish has the right answer.  I tried to add an example as a comment on his answer but was unable to format it clearly, so I'm adding as a separate answer.  Here is an example:

```
% set val "123"
123
% incr val
124
% puts $val
124
% set val "abc"
abc
% incr val
expected integer but got "abc"
% puts $val
abc
%
```

Answer (score 1):

In Tcl everything is string. Read here http://wiki.tcl.tk/3018

If your are using incr to increment, it will interpret the value and if the value is interpreted to be an integer it will be incremented