# how to represent unsigned 32 bit integer in tcl

Tags: c#, tcl

way to represernt unsigned 32 bit integer in tcl?

code to convert  in  tcl is:

```
 myAttributes=(uint)EAttribute.BASIC | (uint)EAttribute.CAPTURE;
```

Comment: Tcl doesn't have unsigned or 32 bit integers. It has integers of arbitrary width (and sometimes might store them in 32-bit storage space, but that's an implementation detail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is `String` in `TCL` as per this [Link1](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3018) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150291/is-there-an-equivalent-in-tcl-of-string-to-x-functions-found-in-c-stdlib-h)

```
set myAttributes [expr $a | $b]
```

Here,

```
$a is EAttribute.BASIC
$b is EAttribute.CAPTURE
```